# Java - Which IP to use for the ServerSocket and Socket classes?

Tags: java, sockets, server

I just recently found the `ServerSocket` and `Socket` class found in the Java library and so I wanted to make a simple messaging app. The purpose of the app is to be able to communicate with someone on a different network than mine (I am the server side and have my own client side).

Here is the `Messenger_Server.java's` connecting method

```
 public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException{
        InetAddress ip;
        try{
            final int PORT = 444;
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);

            System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
            System.out.println(server.getInetAddress() + "  " + ip.getHostAddress());
            while(true){
                Socket sock = server.accept();
                connectionArray.add(sock);

                System.out.println("Client connected from " + sock.getLocalAddress().getHostName());

                addUserName(sock);

                Messenger_Server_Return chat = new Messenger_Server_Return(sock);
                Thread X = new Thread(chat);
                X.start();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the client's connecting method from `Messenger_Client.java`

```
    public static void connect(){
        try{
            final int PORT = 444;
            // the ip below is the one i get as my ipv4 
            Socket sock = new Socket ("10.122.***.***",PORT);
            System.out.println("you be connected to: " + InetAddress.getByAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress()));

            chatClient = new Messenger_Client(sock);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            out.println(userName);
            out.flush();

            Thread X = new Thread(chatClient);
            X.start();
        }catch (Exception X){
            X.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server not responding.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

So I gave the client side of the program to my friend and he said the host could not be found. Which IP should I use so my friend can connect to my `ServerSocket`, and could there be anything limiting my friend from connecting to me?

Comment: You should use your public IP. You might need to configure port forwarding.

Comment: You should give your friend your public IP address. Open command prompt ( In Windows) and use ipconfig to obtain IPv4 address. There could be issues with firewall, both from OS or router.

Comment: `10.*` IP addresses are local to your subnet. They aren't visible outside.

Comment: So i used my IPv4 , I portforwarded, and i allowed inbound and outbound access from the port through my window's firewall and i get this exception java.net.connectexception connection timed out